# Describe the groups of homomorphisms of the given abelian groups

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

In algebra we have the following problem to solve:

> Describe the groups of homomorphisms of abelian groups.
>
> (a) $\textrm{Hom}(\mathbb{Q} / \mathbb{Z}, \mathbb{Q})$
>
> (b) $\textrm{Hom}(\mathbb{Q}, \mathbb{Q} / \mathbb{Z})$

So first of all, I'm not sure, if I really understand what to do. I assume that I just have to describe the group $\textrm{Hom}(\mathbb{Q/Z,Q})$,
This means that I have to define a group operation and then prove that it satisfies the group axioms, like closedness, associativity, existence of inverses element, existence of an identity element, etc. Is this idea correct?

If so, I would define the operation like this: let $f,g \in \textrm{Hom}(\mathbb{Q/Z,Q})$ then: $$(f\odot g)(x):=f(x)+g(x), \qquad \forall x\in \mathbb{Q}.$$

to check that this operation is closed, we have to show that $$f\odot g \in \textrm{Hom}(\mathbb{Q/Z,Q}), \qquad \forall f,g \in \textrm{Hom}(\mathbb{Q/Z,Q})$$

Proof: Let $f,g \in \forall f,g \in \textrm{Hom}(\mathbb{Q/Z,Q})$. Then,

$$\begin{array}{rclcl}
(f\odot g)(x+y)
    &=& f(x+y)+g(x+y) & \qquad & \text{(by def of $\odot$)} \\
    &=& f(x)+f(y)+g(x)+g(y) & & \\
    &=& f(x)+g(x)+f(y)+g(y) & & \\
    &=& (f\odot g)(x)+(f\odot g)(y). & & \text{($\forall x,y \in \mathbb{Q/Z}$)} 
\end{array}$$

This follows only if $\mathbb{Q}$ is abelian, which is obviously true. Also from this fact follows that: $$(f\odot g)(x)=f(x)+g(x)=g(x)+f(x)=(g\odot f)(x), \qquad \forall x \in \mathbb{Q/Z},$$
and hence $\textrm{Hom}(\mathbb{Q/Z,Q})$ is abelian.

It remains only to show that there exist inverses and an identity element.
As identity element we could take the embedding  $e: \mathbb{Q/Z} \hookrightarrow \mathbb{Q}.$

For the inverse I did this:
$(f\odot g)(x)=e(x)=x$, $\forall x \in \mathbb{Q/Z}$ , so
$$(f\odot g)(x)=f(x)+g(x)=x$$
and so
$f(x)^{-1}:=g(x)=x-f(x)$ should be the inverse.
Is this correct, or am I completely on the wrong trail?

Comment: I think that the exercise assumes as a know fact that for abelian groups $A,B$, $\hom(A,B)$ is naturally embedded with an abelian group structure. The goal of the exercise is to give an expression of the groups.

Comment: I don't know exactly what you mean by "expression" of the group, could you explain it a bit

Comment: What is the embedding $\mathbb{Q} / \mathbb{Z} \hookrightarrow \mathbb{Q}$?

Comment: the embedding $e:\mathbb{Q/Z} \hookrightarrow \mathbb{Q}$ just takes values $x \in \mathbb{Q/Z}$ and maps them to $x$, because $\mathbb{Q/Z} \subset \mathbb{Q}$ $\Rightarrow e(x)=x,  \forall x \in \mathbb{Q/Z}$

Comment: No, it doesn't. Let that $x$ be represented by $a/b$. Then $x+x+\cdots+x$ $b$ times equals zero in $\Bbb Q/\Bbb Z$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $A$ and $B$ are abelian groups, then $\operatorname{Hom}(A,B)$ is an abelian group under the obvious operations and I don't think you have to discuss them, because it's general knowledge.

If $A$ is a torsion abelian group and $B$ is a torsion free abelian group, then $\operatorname{Hom}(A,B)=\{0\}$ and this settles the first part. Why is that? If $f\colon A\to B$ is a homomorphism and $x\in A$, choose $n>0$ such that $nx=0$; then $0=f(0)=f(nx)=nf(x)$; since $B$ is torsion free, this implies $f(x)=0$.

A good starting point for the second part is to consider the exact sequence
$$
\def\Z{\mathbb{Z}}\def\Q{\mathbb{Q}}
\def\Hom{\operatorname{Hom}}\def\Ext{\operatorname{Ext}}
0\to\Z\to\Q\to\Q/\Z\to0
$$
and apply the $\Hom(\Q,-)$ functor, which gives the exact sequence
$$
0=\Hom(\Q,\Z)\to\Hom(\Q,\Q)\to\Hom(\Q,\Q/\Z)\to\Ext(\Q,\Z)\to\Ext(\Q,\Q)=0
$$
Now, what's $\Ext(\Q,\Z)$? It's isomorphic to the additive group of the real numbers, as shown by Wiegold ([Bull. Austral. Math. Soc. 1 (1969), 341–343](http://journals.cambridge.org/download.php?file=%2FBAZ%2FBAZ1_03%2FS0004972700042222a.pdf&code=56c22db8fa2702f85d1724b76fbc7feb)).

Since $\Hom(\Q,\Q)\cong\Q$ is divisible, the sequence splits, so we get that
$$
\Hom(\Q,\Q/\Z)\cong \Q\oplus\mathbb{R}\cong\mathbb{R}.
$$

Comment: why $\mathbb{Q} \oplus \mathbb{R} \cong \mathbb{R} $ ?

Comment: @WLOG Because $\mathbb{R}$ is an infinite dimensional vector space over $\mathbb{Q}$, so adding a copy of $\mathbb{Q}$ gives an isomorphic vector space. There's no “canonical” isomorphism, though.

Comment: thanks a lot for your answer